# Short riddle, inspired by a word

Tags: riddle, word

```
As a lass I’d wait forever    
And once it happened we mixed together.    
Lines got crossed,    
Love was lost.    
And just as two becomes one,    
One turned to none    
And left the floor a bit wetter.
```

What is the word that inspired me?

**Hint 1**

> This word can be a verb or a noun

**Hint 2**

> Each line hints to a different aspect of the word

**Hint 3**

> It's a 5 letter word

**Hint 4**

> One of the guesses below uses the word in a different tense

Comment: Is it Weather or Climate related..?

Comment: No it's not weather or climate related.

Comment: Is the answer, or some of its explanation, at all sexual in nature? Asking very objectively, since most of my guesses don't fit with the last line.

Comment: The last line definitely isnt, but the second line partly. The answer isnt though.

Comment: Alright, I'll make my guess, although I am unsure about some of the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'm reaching, because I don't like how I fit almost everything, but maybe it's...

> Bleed

---

`As a lass I’d wait forever`

> For as long as you can stay unhurt, you never have to bleed

`And once it happened we mixed together.`

> Like paint that bleeds together

`Lines got crossed,`

> Paint bleed can be a real problem in creating clean lines, unless you have FrogTape (®)

`Love was lost.`

> [Bleeding Through - Love Lost In A Hail of Gunfire - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G841df0G-CM)

`And just as two becomes one,`

> Once bled together

`One turned to none`

> Now you've bled out

`And left the floor a bit wetter.`

> And left the floor stained with what was

Comment: How do your interpretations of the first 4 lines connect to what you think is the solution?

Comment: ...this is actually the correct answer. Wrong interpretations for the majority of them though. The last interpretations are pretty close. 2 colors bleed together; you bleed out and die; and when you do, a puddle forms on the floor. But to be marked as the correct answer, you'll have to address each line correctly. Each line can be taken separately, I put them in this order to make it flow well together and make a sort of story, but it doesn't necessarily have to do with it. Each addresses different aspects of the word.

Comment: 1) Wait and Bleed is a song by Slipknot - 2) Bleeding Love? a 'Leona Lewis' song apparently - 3) bleeding ink? - 4) a bleeding heart / my heart bleeds?

Comment: That's fair. I should've tried harder instead of just leaving the story.. I updated my answer. Hopefully it's more along the lines of what you were thinking. I'm guessing because it works so well as a poem that each line isn't a specific, obscure reference as Brent is leaning, but do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't see your updates, some are still slightly off, but I'll mark you as correct. @BrentHackers you were correct about bleeding love in regards to love was lost. When you lose someone you love, it is often said that you have a bleeding heart. Regarding lines crossed, I was referencing the bleed of an artboard/paper, the lines past the edge that the design goes to/crosses. As a girl, many girls eagerly anticipate their first menstrual bleeding because it means they are entering womanhood, it means they are growing up.

Answer (score 8):

If you are...

> Juliet, from *Romeo and Juliet*,

...then you are inspired by the word

> Romeo!

`As a lass I’d wait forever`

> I'm unsure about the accuracy of this line. But Juliet is a young lady (lass) and there are parts of the play where Juliet waits for Romeo.

`And once it happened we mixed together.`

> Romeo and Juliet basically fell in love soon after they met.

`Lines got crossed,`

> Romeo's family (Montague) and Juliet's family (Capulet) were enemies. Their romance crossed the "line" between the two families.

`Love was lost.`

> But Romeo and Juliet die in the end!

`And just as two becomes one,`

> First, Romeo drinks poison and dies. Two (Romeo and Juliet) becomes one (Juliet).

`One turned to none`

> Then Juliet stabs herself with a dagger, and dies. One becomes zero (since both are dead).

`And left the floor a bit wetter.`

> After stabbing herself, Juliet presumably bled onto the floor.

Comment: Really good guess, you're on the right track. The word is not a person though.

Comment: I will say, that two of your interpretations were almost spot on though! Thought I had wrote more in my comment before, I must have not saved the update at the time.

Answer (score 3):

is it possibly:

> crush?

As a lass I’d wait forever

> girls usually wait for guys to ask them out...so they can have an unrequited crush forever...which sucks. but...culture, society...yea

And once it happened we mixed together.

> when two things are crushed next to each other, they usually mix

Lines got crossed

> could allude to once someone acknowledges a mutual like, they "just friends" line gets crossed?

Love was lost.

> results in someone being crushed

And just as two becomes one,

> 2 individuals become 1 couple

One turned to none

> when they break up o.o?

And left the floor a bit wetter

> if you crush an orange over the floor, the juice comes out lol. or when you cry, your tears wet the floor.

Comment: Just as above, you're on the right track with some of your interpretations. Great guess

Answer (score 1):

Is the word that inspired you a

> drink?

As a lass I’d wait forever

> Could refer to girls at bars waiting for someone to buy them a drink

And once it happened we mixed together.

> Perhaps the drink initiated a conversation which led to a relationship, love / sex ("mixing together")

Lines got crossed,

> Again not sure, but it could refer to excessive drinking leading to one of the partners "crossing a line" either verbally or physically

Love was lost.

> Obviously it would have led to the end of the relationship, as drinking (or too much of it) often does.

And just as two becomes one,

> A break-up would cause "two to become one"

One turned to none

> Pure speculation, could possibly refer to suicide

And left the floor a bit wetter.

> Most probably due to tears, the family / ex-partner crying about the loss.

Very speculative, I paint a dark picture with my explanations.

P.S. it fits hints 1, 3, 4. Maybe my wacky explanations are why it doesn't fit hint #2

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect, if it was drink I probably would have made some other sort of references to that word rather than seeming so cryptic.

Answer (score -1):

It is

> a glass / a tumbler (which is shaped like - a female/lass - wider top part, narrower mid-part and a wider base!) used for toast partially filled up with alcohol

As a lass I’d wait forever

> a partially filled up(with alcohol / toast of liqid) glass waits for other liquid(s) such as water

And once it happened we mixed together.

> tumbler gets filled with alcohol and diluted and mixed

Lines got crossed,

> Lines (the visibly distinct levels) of alcohol / water gets mixed up

Love was lost.

> Usually alcohol is water-seeking( as its preparation demands this) and once mixed with water, love is lost, lust begins !

And just as two becomes one,

> Lust between alcohol and water justifies this and become a homogenous liquid

One turned to none

> when emptied, one glass-full becomes none !

And left the floor a bit wetter.

> Occassionally this is a case with alcoholic back-ground

Comment: Very interesting idea...but also very reaching.